# Get constructor' value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I have `Base_Model`, `Venue_Model` and `Venue_Controller` class.
Here's my code:

```
var connection = require('../config/db.js');


class Base_Model{
    constructor(){}
readAll(params){
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM ?", params.table, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if ( err ) {
            return reject( err );
          }
          return resolve(rows);
        } );

      });
}

}

module.exports = Base_Model;
```

//Venue_Model is subclass of Base_Model

```
var connection = require('../config/db.js');
var Base_Model = require('../models/Base_Model.js');

class Venue_Model extends Base_Model{
    constructor(params, params_2){
        super();
        this.table = params.table;
        this.venue_id = params_2.venue_id
        this.nama_venue = params_2.nama_venue
        this.keterangan = params_2.keterangan
    }
}

module.exports = Venue_Model;
```

Venue_Controller Class:

```
var Venue_Model = require('../models/Venue_Model.js');
var params = {
    table : 'venue'
}
var params_2 = {
    venue_id : null,
    nama_venue : null,
    keterangan : null
}
var venue_model = new Venue_Model(params, params_2);

class Venue_Controller{
    constructor(){}

getDataVenue(req, res){

    venue_model.readAll()
    .then(function(result){
        if(result){
            res.render('manajemen_list_venue/manajemen_list_venue', {
                        person: req.user,
                        venues: result,
                        message_err: req.flash('message_err'),
                        message_success: req.flash('message_success'),

            }); 
        }
        else{
            req.flash('message_notf', "No venue found.");
            res.render('manajemen_list_venue/manajemen_list_venue', {
                person: req.user,
                message_err: req.flash('message_err'),
                message_success: req.flash('message_success'),
                message_notf: req.flash('message_notf')

            });
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        req.flash('message_err', err");
        res.redirect('/manajemen_list_venue');
    })


}
```

}

I pass parameter `params` and `params_2` in object `venue_model` in `Venue_Controller`. So How if i want to pass `params` and `params_2` as arguments of `getDataVenue` function which is called via instance of `Venue_Model`?

Comment: Can you provide a smaller reproducible example?

Comment: How about not constructing the `var venue_model = new Venue_Model(params, params_2);` in the static module scope, but inside the `getDataVenue` function?

Comment: Btw, you're not passing any `params` into the `readAll` call.

Comment: @Bergi ya i confuse how to pass params to readAll(). What u suggest?

Comment: @Bergi actually idk what is the benefit of using class instead of just put the functions in static modul scope and load it using require()

Comment: @hfbachri_ In the code you posted, there is absolutely zero benefit of using `class`es with methods over plain `function`s. Why did you use `class` syntax in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi so what u suggest me to change if i wanna get benefit of classes?

Comment: @hfbachri_ What would that "benefit of classes" be that you're talking about?

Comment: @Bergi all of that. All of the benefits i possibly achieve when i use class instead of just declare my functions inside static module scope

Comment: @hfbachri_ All of *what*? I just told you that there are no benefits.

Comment: @Bergi so no benefit of using "class" in express?

Comment: @hfbachri_ I just told you that in the code you posted, there is no benefit of using `class`, yes. You're not really using the instance objects anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi Nah. I was asking you how to improve my code so i can achieve the benefits of using class. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: @hfbachri_ There are no benefits of using `class`, and you cannot use it anyway if you don't use objects!